# "CSRF verification failed. Request aborted" while making json request

Tags: javascript, django, json, backbone.js, csrf

While making json request from backbone.js app, I'm getting an error:

> CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

I have set the `X-CRSF-TOKEN`, but still it showing `403 forbidden` error .

In backbone,js app i have the following code:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter( function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
        options.xhrFields = {
          withCredentials: true
        };
        // If we have a csrf token send it through with the next request
        console.log("that.get('_csrf')");
        console.log(that.get('_csrf'));
        if(typeof that.get('_csrf')  !== 'undefined') {
         jqXHR.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', that.get('_csrf'));
        }
      });
    },
```

In console i have the crsf token value:

> X-CSRF-Token:V30RZC23TQ015YQO5KCKCPI2RWSTWIOH

Comment: what is `that` where does it come from? CSRF are per session/connection, they cannot be reused. They should be obtained from the page you are accessing.

Comment: And `this` object is? I mean, where does _csrf come from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.- CSRF cookie not set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498682/django-csrf-verification-failed-request-aborted-csrf-cookie-not-set)