# CSRF token missing, causing verification failure in Django app's login form (accessed over a forward proxy)

Tags: django, csrf, csrf-protection, django-csrf

I maintain a simple Django web application where users congregate and leave each other text + photo messages. The server employs SSL. I also use a CDN to serve static assets, in case that matters.

My problem is that upon trying to log in an existing user, I get a **CSRF Verification failed** error. Peculiarly, many users report getting this error the *first time* they try logging in, but that it works the second time around right after. *Also, a proxy is involved in between - all the reporters of this error are on the said proxy.* Without the proxy, it works perfectly. Looking at `Resources` in Developer Tools for Chrome, I've found that the CSRF token is correctly present when the website is accessed without the proxy in the middle, but is **entirely missing** when on the proxy.

What special measures am I to take on this?

---

I use a vanilla logging in process, i.e. a contrib function. In my urls.py, I have the url pattern:

```
url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name="login"),
```

In settings.py, I have:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
 #   'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'myproject.middleware.XForwardedFor.XForwardedForMiddleware',
    'user_sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    #'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'myproject.middleware.HellBanned.HellBannedMiddleware',
    #'request.middleware.RequestMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'mobileesp.middleware.MobileDetectionMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

Whereas the login function in views.py found in django.contrib.auth is:

```
@sensitive_post_parameters()
@csrf_protect
@never_cache
def login(request, template_name='registration/login.html',
          redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME,
          authentication_form=AuthenticationForm,
          current_app=None, extra_context=None):
    """
    Displays the login form and handles the login action.
    """
    redirect_to = request.REQUEST.get(redirect_field_name, '')

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = authentication_form(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            # Ensure the user-originating redirection url is safe.
            if not is_safe_url(url=redirect_to, host=request.get_host()):
                redirect_to = resolve_url(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)

            # Okay, security check complete. Log the user in.
            auth_login(request, form.get_user())

            if request.session.test_cookie_worked():
                request.session.delete_test_cookie()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
    else:
        form = authentication_form(request)

    request.session.set_test_cookie()

    current_site = get_current_site(request)

    context = {
        'form': form,
        redirect_field_name: redirect_to,
        'site': current_site,
        'site_name': current_site.name,
    }
    if extra_context is not None:
        context.update(extra_context)
    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context,
                            current_app=current_app)
```

Is the above function missing anything? BTW, my login template is quite simply:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<div class="margin">
<form method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">

    <p>{{ 'Nickname:' }}
      {{ form.username }}</p>

    <p>  {{ 'Password:' }}
      {{ form.password }}</p>


  <input class="button" type="submit" value="OK"><br>

</form>
<br>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Ideally, I don't want to use `csrf exempt`, since I feel that's a workaround, and doesn't really untangle this tangle.

Can anyone please advise what I need to do? I've seen similar questions asked on SO before, but they don't work for me because:

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498682/django-csrf-verification-failed-request-aborted-csrf-cookie-not-set): this OP had written an erroneous method in views.py, whereas I'm simply relying on the vanilla `django.contrib.auth.views.login` method. As the [docs state](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#csrf-cookie-domain):  If you’re using the render() function, generic views, **or contrib apps**, you are covered already since these all use RequestContext.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498682/django-csrf-verification-failed-request-aborted-csrf-cookie-not-set): Same problem as above it seems.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692625/csrf-verification-failed-request-aborted-on-django?rq=1): this OP was missing `{% csrf_token %}` in her Django template, I'm not.

Thanks in advance. I'm a newbie in this domain, so apologies if the solution is obvious and it's eluding me. Btw, in case it matters, I employ legacy Django (v 1.5.1) for this particular project.

Comment: Which proxy is it running through? Since it works perfectly fine without a proxy, I think we'll need the proxy config.

Comment: @KeenanLawrence: Thanks for the insight Keenan. It's actually a proxy under Facebook's 'next billion' initiative internet.org (called Free Basics). I'm going to message their engineers for the information. Anything *specific* I should ask them to dig out for us?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know what specifics to ask for. Do you perhaps have `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True` in your settings?

Comment: @KeenanLawrence: no, I don't. In any case, I've passed a message to Facebook's team. Watch this space for updates, and thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks, please post a solution to this once you've figured it out :)